# How to apply filter in quicksight so that it scans only applied filter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I am using Athena as data source in quicksight.

How to apply filter on a column so that it scans only those ?

I have created a table in Athena as `table1`.  And I have used **partition projection** on (`event_date date`) . The partition projection is working in Athena and data is populating there.

But when I used Quicksight to create a dashboard. I applied a filter on `event_date`, It fires a query to Athena and in `where` clause, It gives the `event_date` as

```
event_date=date_trunc('day', FROM_UNIXTIME(TO_UNIXTIME(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(TO_UNIXTIME(CAST(PARSE_DATETIME('2023-03-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

and It scans all the partition in the table because `trunc_date function truncates the given timestamp to '2023-03-01 00:00:00.000'`. And gives the error

```
HIVE_EXCEEDED_PARTITION_LIMIT: Query over table 'sample_db.table1' can potentially read more than 1000000 partitions
```

But when `event_date string` then in that case while applying the filter in quicksight it scans only given event_date.

How to fix this issue. So that It scans only given number of partition in case of `event_date` as date also?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case , we can use Quicksight **Dataset Parameter** to control the query scanning.

The query will look like this:-
First we have to create two parameter fromDate and toDate in dataset.

```
select * from table where date between <<$frmomDate>> and <<$toDate>>
```

After this , we have to map this dataset parameter to analysis parameter.